# I am trying to use @layers with CSS v3

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to use layers with CSS v3.

while compiling the CSS It's throwing :
Error: undefined:82:3: missing '}' css/lib/parse/index.js:62:15

my sample code :

```js
var css = require('css');
var obj = css.parse("@layer mylayer {.card {--content-box-flex-grow: 1; display: flex; flex-direction: column; position: relative; width: 100%;} }");
css.stringify(obj);
```

npm runkit :

https://runkit.com/embed/3hk0f1iymtil

Comment: My guess is that the `css` module doesn't support `@layer`.

Comment: CSS layers are a part of "CSS Cascading and Inheritance Level 5"; it's still a candidate version, that was proposed originaly in 2021. The CSS module is much older than that and they don't really maintain "candidate" proposals. If you search in a repo, there's nothing about `@layer` in the code.